# How to find the length of a line segment in a rectangle

Tags: geometry

there is a rectangle abcd (vertexs) and there is point labeled P inside the rectangle. AP=55 PD=60 PC =33 what is PB

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  What have you tried?

Comment: what do  you mean

Comment: What work have you done on the problem?

Comment: I tried to determine the length of PB using AD as a variable length but that didn't work out

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  Draw the lines $PA,PB,PC,PD$ and also the perpendiculars from $P$ to the sides of the rectangle.  Then you will see eight right-angled triangles.  Now use Pythagoras' Theorem (more than once).

Comment: k thx I think I have it